# How to show Year, date and day along with Time in windows taskbar?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

How to show Year, date and day along with Time in windows taskbar? through autohotkey

Comment: I dont think autohotkey is required, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm...

[image]

I've got:

- Year,
- date,
- day,
- Time, and
- AutoHotkey  :)

I fear I may have missed the point of your question though.  I'm not sure how AutoHotkey is required to display the items you asked about.

Comment: AutoHotkey is not required, see http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2301/xp_display_date_system_tray_taskbar/

Answer (score 0):

Try [TClockEx](http://www.rcis.co.za/dale/tclockex/).

> TClockEx enhances the standard Windows taskbar clock, adding the ability to display the date, time and lots of other information in any format you like. TClockEx is highly customizable, from the format to the font and colour, and even the tooltip information. Many people have wondered why this wasn't built into the standard clock to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Without using extra tools you can just enlarge the taskbar (see [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2301/xp_display_date_system_tray_taskbar/))

Answer (score 0):

unlock the taskbar and increase its height

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the size of the taskbar, you can use [T-Clock Redux](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock) (it's newer than TClockEx and T-Clock) or [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/t-clock-redux/) to customize the taskbar clock format (and font/fontsize to make it fit with line breaks). Example format: `hh:nn\ndddd` (`\n` stands for newline).

Note that you can instead [change the date format in system settings](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-day-of-week-to-taskbar-windows), but [that affects other programs](https://superuser.com/q/745759/498103).