# Show day of week and date in Windows taskbar (without changing taskbar size)

Tags: windows

The clock in the Windows taskbar shows the date if it has medium size (two rows), and it shows additionally the *day of the week* if it is huge (three rows).

How can the *day of the week* and date be displayed in Windows taskbar, but without making the taskbar size huge?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101148/discussion-between-root-and-jw0914).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the size of the taskbar, you can use [T-Clock Redux](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock) or [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/t-clock-redux/) to customize the taskbar clock format (and font/fontsize to make it fit with line breaks). Example format: `hh:nn\ndddd` (`\n` stands for newline).

Note that you can instead [change the date format in system settings](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-day-of-week-to-taskbar-windows), but [that affects other programs](https://superuser.com/q/745759/498103).

Answer (score 0):

T-Clock Redux no longer works for me as of the time of this posting (in Windows 10).

But, after a LOT of checking around, I found this tool:

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/tclock_win10.html

It claims to work with both Windows 10 and 11. It shows a lot more than just the clock, but that is all I was after.

Before use, edit the .ini file in the folder and set EnglishMenu=1 (if you speak English). After that, run the program and right-click to get to preferences. I got my clock & date showing perfectly the way I want with small icons turned on.

Once you're happy, place a shortcut to the executable in your "Startup" folder so it runs when Windows starts.